# Extraer el último elemento de cada entrada del mapa?

Tags: java, map

Tengo un mapa y quiero extraer el último valor para cada clave de ese mapa, pero no lo consigo:

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> mapNombreClaseYPropiedades = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String,String> valores = mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.get(this.almacenNombreClase); //valores son los propios valores de mapNombreClaseYPropiedades


                valores.forEach((k,v)->
                {

                    try{
                        //AQUI QUIERO REALIZAR LA COMPROBACIÓN PARA ENTRADA DE VALORES Y COGER LA ÚLTIMA ENTRADA
                        if(v.equals("NUM")){
                            fichero.write("Integer " + k + ",");

                        }else{
                            fichero.write("String " + k + ",");
                   
                        }
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
```

Es decir, si tengo por ejemplo en el `mapNombreClaseYPropiedades`:

```
Clave:Profesor , Valores : {texto=TXT, tipo=TXT, prueba=NUM, dificultad=NUM}
Clave:Examen , Valores :{texto:TXT,nivel:NUM}
```

Extraer **dificultad=NUM y nivel=NUM**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, en general `Map` no ordena los valores. `LinkedHashMap` sí que lo hace. Así que lo suyo es que las variables sean del tipo adecuado para dejar claro que son `LinkedHashMap`. Es decir:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String,String>> mapNombreClaseYPropiedades = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LinkedHashMap<String,String> valores = mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.get(this.almacenNombreClase); //valores son los propios valores de mapNombreClaseYPropiedades
```

De otra forma, te arriesgas a que en algún momento tu código asigne un `HashMap` o `TreeMap` con resultados inesperados.

En segundo lugar, no todo tiene que hacerse con *streams*. Por ejemplo

```
String ultimaClave = null;
for (String clave : v.keySet() {
   ultimaClave = clave;
}
// Aquí lo que quieras hacer con la última clave. Asegúrate de que no sea null.
```

Comment: Pero lo que me gustaría a parte de su buena respuesta, es añadir una condición ahí de sí es el último hacer X cosas. Eso no es posible?

Comment: Bueno. En `ultimaClave` tienes la clave del último elemento del mapa. Y con `v.get(ultimaClave)` el último valor. Con eso haces lo que quieras.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `Iterator` para lograr extraer los últimos elementos:

```
    //Obtiene último elemento de primer Map.
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.entrySet().iterator();
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = null, firstEntry = null, lastEntry = null;        
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        entry = iterator.next();
        if(firstEntry == null)
            firstEntry = entry;
        lastEntry = entry;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Último elemento: " + lastEntry);
          
    //Obtiene último elemento de segundo Map.  
    iterator = valores.entrySet().iterator();        
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        entry = iterator.next();
        if(firstEntry == null)
            firstEntry = entry;
        lastEntry = entry;
    }
            
    System.out.println("Último elemento: " + lastEntry);
```

De esta forma tendrías como salida:

```
Último elemento: dificultad=NUM
Último elemento: nivel=NUM
```